# Apple TextEdit, Where does its toolbar come from?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to implement a text editor like Apple TextEdit. So I read the source of Apple [TextEdit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html). I found its toolbar is unlike mine, there are no fonts, no font colors on mine. My toolbar is from menu `format - text - Show Ruler`, but Apple TextEdit's is not, it is always there, can't be hidden. But I can't find the toolbar in any nib file in its source code. So where does its toolbar come from? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: By and large, this is just different control styles. Apple now prefers the _textured square_ or _textured rounded_ styles. Fiddle with the control styles until you get the look you want. Refer to the latest Apple Human Interface Guidelines for their current recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.
Select your `NSTextView` on nib or storyboard, on its Attributes inspector, check the `Inspector Bar` option.
[image]